# How to disable youtube link from iframe

Tags: html, reactjs, youtube

I'm embedding a youtube iframe video player in my website made with React. I don't want there any clickable link in that area, more specifically I want to restrict the youtube link to load from inside the iframe elements.

look at the red mark area, if I click there, it opens youtube.com

Is there any way to restrict "youtube.com" from my site that will prevent me to click or something like this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you won't be able to hide youtube watermark anyway

Answer (score 1):

`modestbranding=1`
This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar. Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding